# How can I split an expression onto multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, string-formatting

How can I split an assignment like this onto two lines?

```
myLongVariableName = 'some somewhat long format string like this %s' % myOtherVariable
```

I tried a few variations:

```
myLongVariableName = 'some somewhat long format string like this %s' 
  % myOtherVariable

myLongVariableName = 'some somewhat long format string like this %s' %
  myOtherVariable

myLongVariableName = 
'some somewhat long format string like this %s' % myOtherVariable
```

My searching is coming up short.  What I've found mostly talks about indenting blocks of code or parameters, not long expressions.

Comment: I just found that I can use a backslash at the end of the line.  Is there another way?  I consider lines ending with backslashes poor style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated in Python:

```
myLongVariableName = ('some somewhat long format'
                      'string like this %s') % myOtherVariable
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an option:

```
myLongVariableName = 'some somewhat long format string like this {}'
    .format(myOtherVariable)
```

Read more about it:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format